# mongoengine aggregate lookup on _id not working

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

Campaign Record

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64eb81337f7d9f6e1107fc3a"
  },
  "_cls": "CampaignModel",
  "campaignNumber": "CMPN-00005",
  "account": {
    "$oid": "64d80694fe75052b39c0e615"
  },
  "campaignName": "title",
  "campaignDescription": "wdesc",
  "campaignStartDate": {
    "$date": "2023-08-17T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "campaignEndDate": {
    "$date": "2023-08-27T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "isWorkOrderGeneratedFlag": false,
  "isInvoiceGenerated": false,
  "campaignCost": "20000",
  "clientName": "",
  "attachedBillboardList": [],
  "accountId": "64d80694fe75052b39c0e615"
}
```

Booking Record

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64eb81337f7d9f6e1107fc3b"
  },
  "_cls": "BookingModel",
  "campaignId": "64eb81337f7d9f6e1107fc3a",
  "billboardId": "64e0d18aaec5d7ef7bf848dd",
  "startDate": {
    "$date": "2023-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "endDate": {
    "$date": "2023-09-10T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "costPerDay": 200,
  "billboard": {
    "_ref": {
      "$ref": "BillBoard",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "64e0d18aaec5d7ef7bf848dd"
      }
    },
    "_cls": "BillBoardModel"
  }
}
```

I am trying to join the campaign with booking on `_id` from the campaign record and `campaignId` in the booking record.

Campaign Mongoengine class

```
class CampaignModel(BaseModel):
    meta = {'collection': 'Campaign'}
    campaignNumber = me.SequenceField(sequence_name="CAMPAIGN",  value_decorator=generate_campaign_number)
    account = me.ReferenceField(UserModel)
    campaignName = me.StringField()
    campaignDescription = me.StringField()
    campaignStartDate = me.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    campaignEndDate = me.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    isWorkOrderGeneratedFlag = me.BooleanField(default=False)
    isInvoiceGenerated = me.BooleanField(default=False)
    campaignCost = me.StringField()
    clientName = me.StringField()
    attachedBillboardList = me.ListField()
```

Booking Mongoengine Class

```
class BookingModel(BaseModel):
    meta = {'collection': 'Booking'}
    campaignId = me.StringField()
    campaign = me.LazyReferenceField(CampaignModel,dbref=False)
    billboardId = me.StringField()
    accountId = me.StringField()
    billBoard = me.LazyReferenceField(BillBoardModel,dbref=False)
    startDate = me.DateField()
    endDate = me.DateField()
    costPerDay = me.FloatField()
```

query

```
records = CampaignModel.objects.aggregate(*[
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "Booking",  # Tag collection database name
                    "localField": "_id",  # Reference field
                    "foreignField": "campaignId",  # Primary key of the Tag collection
                    "as": "attaches"
                }

            }])
```

Expected:
Records from campaign collection with records from Booking collection as an array in `attaches` key.

But the `attaches` key was empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was you were storing the `campaignId` as a string type in the Booking collection. Make sure that both values to be compared must be same type before comparing. Thus, you need to convert the `campaignId` for the document in the Booking collection as `ObjectId` type as below:

```
db.Campaign.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Booking",
      let: {
        campaignId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$campaignId",
                {
                  $toObjectId: "$campaignId"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "attaches"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2w4uwayj2II)

Comment: the funny thing is it was somehow working for some time with the same code. any guesses , i thought that with pymongo we needed to convert this objectID and with mongoengine this convertion was not required